# Listen to reducer state change in component in redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using redux-saga in my react application. I have to fetch a list of orders and display in the component. I had created actions and reducers and saga for the same.

I am hitting the API in the saga and

**saga**

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { path } from "ramda";
import OrdersActions from "../Redux/OrdersRedux";
export function* getOrders(api, action) {
  const { header } = action;
  console.log("order header", action);
  // make the call to the api
  const response = yield call(api.getOrders, header);
  console.log(response);
  if (response.ok) {
    yield put(OrdersActions.success(response.data));
    // do data conversion here if needed
  } else {
    yield put(OrdersActions.failure());
  }
}
```

**reducer**

```
import { createReducer, createActions } from 'reduxsauce'
import Immutable from 'seamless-immutable'

/* ------------- Types and Action Creators ------------- */

const { Types, Creators } = createActions({
  getOrders: ['header'],
  success: ["data"],
  failure: [],
})

export const OrderTypes = Types
export default Creators

/* ------------- Initial State ------------- */

export const INITIAL_STATE = Immutable({
  new_orders: [],
  fetching: null,
  error: null,
})

/* ------------- Reducers ------------- */

// request the avatar for a user

export const getOrdersRequest = (state) =>
  state.merge({ fetching: true })

// successful avatar lookup
export const success = (state, action) => {
  const { data } = action;
  return state.merge({ fetching: false, error: null, new_orders: data.data.new_orders })
}

// failed to get the avatar
export const failure = (state) =>
  state.merge({ fetching: false, error: true })


/* ------------- Hookup Reducers To Types ------------- */

export const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {
  [Types.GET_ORDERS]: getOrdersRequest,
  [Types.SUCCESS]: success,
  [Types.failure]: failure,
})
```

MyComponent.js

```
class OrdersScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = getHeaderStyle("Orders");

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      new_orders: this.props.order_details.new_orders
    }
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getOrders(this.getHeader());
  }


  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps, props) {
    if (newProps.order_details.new_orders.length > 0) {
      this.setState({
        new_orders: newProps.order_details.new_orders
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: "flex-start" }}>
        <View style={{ padding: 10, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Text style={{ flex: 3 }}>Order</Text>
        </View >
        {
            this.state.new_orders.map((item)=>{
                return<div>{item.order_id}</div>
            })
        }
        <View>
          <Button label="Make Payment" onPress={this.onMakePaymentClick()} />
        </View >
      </View>
    )
  }

  getHeader() {
    const { session_id } = this.props;
    return { "x-session-id": session_id };
  }

  onMakePaymentClick = () => {
    this.props.submitOrders();
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    order_details: state.order_details,
  }
}



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getOrders: (header) => dispatch(OrdersActions.getOrders(header)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(OrdersScreen)
```

My Question is there any other way to know that the a value is changed in store and get the changed value ?.

I am using **componentWillReceiveProps** method for any new change in store.

Now I want to dispatch another action "MakePayment" and hit another api and if the response is ok I want to change the screen else show error message.

As you can see I am setting new_orders  in state in **componentWillReceiveProps** . If I dispatch "MakePayment" action this will call componentWillReceiveProps again and the orders will re-render.

**How to avoid this ? And is there any other a component can listen to a change in the store and value which is changed  ?**

Comment: you can set if component updates or not with [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: i want to update my component only when the payment is success or failed

Comment: And more over i have to add a lot of conditions in shouldComponentUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps. I have to check multiple states and props. This is making it complex. Instead if there was a event listener which triggers when a particular store value is changed and give the changed value it will make life easier. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should dispatch your action from componentDidMount. The [componentWillMount docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) explains why.

Second, you don't need to use `componentWillReceiveProps` to pick up changes because you only dispatch `getOrders` once. The data is going straight to your `new_orders` prop. Indeed, since you just care about the `new_orders`, you should set this directly as a prop. That way your component observes directly to the changes in `new_orders`.

Finally, if you call a 'MAKE_PAYMENT' action, that won't generate a re-render because the payment data won't be in your props or state. Remember that when you have data in a prop, you don't need to pass it into a state unless you have a really good reason.